# Apply function to dynamically generated elements

Tags: jquery

I've just installed this [script](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric) to format input fields as float numbers:

```
   $(selector).autoNumeric("init",{
        aSep: '.',
        aDec: ',', 
        aSign: '€ '
    });
```

I works like a charm, but now I'm wondering what code should I add to bind the function to dynamically generated elements, that is new elements. Any help?

**EDIT**: after the answer of Patrick, the code below is working ok (being `.text-primary` the class of the element clicked to show the input text I want to give format using the script I mention below):

```
    $('.text-primary').on('click', function() {
      $('#bill_servicesPerformed_0_unitPrice').autoNumeric("init",{
        aSep: '.',
        aDec: ',',
        aSign: '' 
      });
    });
```

but not this:

```
    $('body #bill_servicesPerformed_0_unitPrice').autoNumeric("init",{
        aSep: '.',
        aDec: ',',
        aSign: '' 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like:

```
$("body selector").autoNumeric("init", { //code here });
```

Or wrap your code in a `function` and call that `function` after you add your new elements.

Comment: your first solution is not working but the second yes. Anyway Im curious about why the fist solutions doesn't work.. I have edited my question.

Comment: @ziiweb How about this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhys58gq/) to fix the first one? Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Its late but may be this can help:

For autonumeric fields when we use cloning to generate dynamic fields having a common class(.addcommas). we can use below code inside cloning code...to reinitialise autonumeric on dynamic generated fields.

```
$('.addcommas').autoNumeric('destroy');
$('.addcommas').autoNumeric('init',{aSep: ',', mDec: 2});
```